# Can Cron cause the site to go down or DDos attack?

Tags: ddos

Yesterday I started running a cronjob [code below] on my server

```
('*/1 * * * *', 'api.cron.sync_with_elastic',['nginx-access-logs'])
```

In the morning I got a message that my website is down. I was unable to even SSH, I switched off the server from dashboard my cloud provider has provided and then restarted it. Below is the metric of the website in the last 24 hrs.
[image]

Is this a DDoS attack or cron has caused this issue?

Comment: "cron" does not cause this but the job you run might cause this. Only, it is nothing known what this specific job actually causes on load on your system. If you want to know if this is an externally triggered DDoS you need to look at the network traffic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `*/1 * * * *` equals `* * * * *` i.e. running your cronjob **every minute**. If the task takes longer than a minute and doesn't stop the last run, you end up having multiple tasks running simultaneously. Since that takes more resources, the tasks slows down.

That's a *vicious circle* that over time can lead in exhausting all resources, which will make your server unresponsive. Despite we can't rule out DDoS, this alone can explain your situation. I'd even say it's the most plausible cause.